# second screen configration issue ubuntu 18.04 - amd and intel driver

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, intel-graphics, amdgpu

note- I have explored other similar questions but nothing worked for me.

i am trying to configure dual display setup.
my laptop is detecting 2nd  monitor but it shows nothing but black screen.

after running -

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|Display'
```

output-

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Radeon R5 M330
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

and
for command-

```
xrandr
```

output-

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3360 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1440+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.00 +  59.97*   59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 1440x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 367mm x 229mm
   1440x900      59.89*+  74.98  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

my main display uses **Lenovo Radeon R5 M330** and my secondary display uses **Lenovo Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]**.

how do I configure this?